# Yoctoproject - include newer coreutils (stat)

Tags: yocto, gnu-coreutils

I am trying to build a custom distribution for an embedded device. I need the 'stat'-command (which is part of GNU coreutils) to support long-options, e.g. `stat --printf`.

The stat-version the build currently includes is ancient and does not support long-options.

```
root@target:/# stat -v
stat version 3.0
```

The receipe for stat is located at `sources/poky/meta/recipes-extended/stat_3.3.bb` which points to `http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/utils/file/stat-3.3.tar.gz` as its SRC_URI.

The coreutils receipe is located at `sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/coreutils/coreutils_8.27.bb` which points to `https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-8.27.tar.xz` as its SRC_URI.

How I understand it, bitbake uses `ALTERNATIVE_PRIORITY[stat]` which is defined in both recipes to decide which version is to be included. Since the coreutils_8.27 should be new enough, I tried to simply delete the stat_3.3-receipe. This didn't work, the old 3.3 version of stat is still included.

What would be the best way to include a newer version or coreutils (or stat) which supports long-options?

Answer (score 1):

To fix this I had to include the 'coreutils'-package (`IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " coreutils"`) in my `local.conf` and raise the `ALTERNATIVE_PRIORITY` for the coreutils-package.